# Excel getting max value from alphanumberic with conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I got data from a range of rows (say `A3` to `Z3`) with alphanumeric values (ex: `50D`, `25U`, `30D`, etc..). I need to find the max of these numbers  and apply conditional formatting for the max value.

Previously I tried the below formula in conditional formatting.. but I am not sure how can I compare with alphabets now (I got only 2 alphabets either D or U in these numbers).
Can you help how I can achieve this with the alphanumeric numbers?

`=AND(A3>0,A3=MAX($A3:$Z3))`  --> if I have only numbers this is working.. following is my vb code..

```
myRng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(A3>0,A3=MAX($A3:$Z3))" 
   With myRng.FormatConditions(3)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.TintAndShade = 0
            .Interior.Pattern = xlPatternRectangularGradient
            .Interior.Gradient.RectangleLeft = 0.5
            .Interior.Gradient.RectangleRight = 0.5
            .Interior.Gradient.RectangleTop = 0.5
            .Interior.Gradient.RectangleBottom = 0.5
            .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0).ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0).TintAndShade = 0
            .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1).Color = 4123227 '15525371
            .Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1).TintAndShade = 0
            .StopIfTrue = False
            .SetFirstPriority
    End With
```

Comment: But what is higher? `50D` or `100U`? In other words; how do we handle alphabets in your case?

Comment: what version of Excel?

Comment: @JvdV The alphabets are for just showing direction.. (apart from that no other significant) .

Comment: @Ron Excel 2016 version.

Answer (score 0):

With only those two letters, it's relatively easy.  You just have to strip off the `D` or `U`, and convert the resultant string to a number:

```
=AND(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A$3,"D",""),"U",""))>0, VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A$3,"D",""),"U",""))=MAX(IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A$3:$Z$3,"D",""),"U","")),0)))
```

Note that the `SUBSTITUTE` function will have no affect if the string is not present.

For using the formula in a VBA generated conditional format, you'll need to ensure the addressing is proper, and you also need to escape the included quotation marks, so:

```
    Formula1:= "=AND(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3,""D"",""""),""U"",""""))>0, VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3,""D"",""""),""U"",""""))=MAX(IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A3:$Z3,""D"",""""),""U"","""")),0)))"
```

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for reply, somehow this code is not working in VBA, I mean its not applying conditional applying through vba. But if I edit this rule.. then click ok.. then its working (though i need to manually apply color formatting).. any help below is my vba code.. ( i got multiple conditional formatting rules)

Comment: @bvsnkiran Problem could relate to not escaping the included quote marks; or possibly the relative/absolute addressing used.  I'll post a `Formula1` line that has that corrected.

Comment: I did used the same formula and tried but no luck. I raised separate thread...can u pls help.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65778176/conditional-formatting-is-not-getting-applied-on-the-sheets?noredirect=1#comment116300799_65778176

Comment: @bvsnkiran Works fine here.  How did you define `myRng`? And are you sure you are dealing with `.FormatConditions(3)`? And that `.FormatConditions(1)` and `(2)` are not interfering?

Comment: yes, I need all the format conditions.. but how come it works when I edit the conditional formatting manually..